# js macrotask order, two script tags, first with settimout, still after second script

Tags: javascript, macros

see the code

```html
<script>
  console.log('first script')
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('settimout');
  }, 0);
</script>
<script>
  console.log('second script')
</script>
```

the output is

```
first script
second script
settimout
```

my understanding is
one macro then all aviaiable micro. then second macro.

so when js see the first script tag, it adds the script into the macro queue,
then dequeues the first item (first script tag) and run. Inside the first script, it sees the first log, then just runs it.

Then it sees the `setTimeout`, it is macro, so adds it to the macro queue.

first tag is finished. see if any micro? no. then run second macro which is setimout.

then run second script

so i think the output should be

```
first script
settimout
second script
```

where am I wrong?

any help is appreciated

Comment: Unless the `<script>` tag has the `async` or `defer` attributes, it's loaded synchronously, not through the event queue.

Comment: for me it is logical that setTimeout sets event after all immediate page events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, by default JavaScript, does not have web API features like setTimeout, fetch, etc, There are built-in in the browser. JavaScript first pushes the JavaScript features like console.logs in to call stack and then checks if there are any other things in the microtask queue and macro task queue.

Methods like setTimeout, setInterval will be added to the macro task by default. In the same way methods like fetch, promises, etc will be added to microtask queue.

In this case, first Js engine executes console.log('first script') and encounters setTimeout method, setTimeout method will be pushed to the macro task queue and then Js engine moves on to console.log('second script') and executes it.Js engine checks if there are any things in macrotask queue. As the setTimeout method is there is macrotask queue it will be added into call stack JavaScript engine executes it.

Therefore, the output will be the first script,second script,settimout